# Adding an image to Shiny action button

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny action button but instead of font I wish to display an image. i have used tags$button for the action button. This displays a small grey box. instead i wish to display a "power" button.

```
 fluidRow(
      column(4,offset=11,
        tags$button(
        id = "reset_button",
        class="btn action-button"

        ))),
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's pretty easy with the argument `icon` of the function `actionButton()`:

```
actionButton("goButton", "", icon = icon("play-circle"))
```

Alternatively, you can use the function `icon()` to add an icon to your button code:

```
tags$button(
          id = "reset_button",
          class="btn action-button",
          icon("close")

        )
```

Or you use the `img()` function to use your own:

```
    tags$button(
      id = "web_button",
      class = "btn action_button",
      img(src = "http://www.craftech.com/wp-uploads/2015/05/web.png",
               height = "50px")
    )
```

To get a more comprehensive list of possible icons, take a look at `?icon` help page of the `shiny` package and the links in the `See Also` section.

An example app:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        actionButton("goButton", "", icon = icon("play-circle")),
        tags$button(
          id = "reset_button",
          class="btn action-button",
          icon("close")

        ),
        tags$button(
          id = "web_button",
          class = "btn action-button",
          tags$img(src = "http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/button_play_89677.jpg",
                   height = "50px")
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        textOutput("text")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    out <- reactiveVal("Nothing")
    observeEvent(input$goButton,{
      out("Go Pushed")
    })
    observeEvent(input$reset_button,{
      out("Resetted")
    })
    observeEvent(input$web_button,{
      out("From the web")
    })
    output$text <- renderText({out()})
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  but I do not require to display any text. I only want the logo. Plus i have to use my own image as the logo/icon.

Comment: @MysticRenge You can make the label disappear by setting it to `""`.

Comment: @MysticRenge updated with examples on how you can use custom images and the button tag.

Comment: Hi! I came across this solution and unfortunately I can't link to a local file in the same folder. What can be the cause of the problem? I have

`background: url('Image.png');` but the button always remains empty. Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Alex_ I am not sure you can put an image as background for a button, never tried it myself. Using `img()` as shown above, you should be able to link to a custom image (you don't need `url()`, just the relative path to the image as an argument to `src`)

Answer (score 5):

Here is another simple solution that worked for me:

```
actionButton(inputId = "A.button", label = NULL, style = "width: 50px; height: 50px;
background: url('MyImage.png');  background-size: cover; background-position: center;")
```

the image should be in the www folder inside the app's folder, background size in this case fits image to button size, alternatively you can use `background-repeat: no-repeat;`  to make sure the image is not repeated to fill size,
center center should center the image vertically and horizontally.

One could in principle also put the image as label, like:

```
label = img (src="MyImage.png", width="30", height="30"),
```

However, then the image could stuck out over the edge of the button compared to inserting it as background.

Comment: typo --  colon after `height: 50px:` should be semicolon  `height: 50px;`