# actionButton in Shiny DataTable that has a Different on-click URL by Row

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, action-button

I am trying to create an action button in a Shiny DataTable that when clicked links to a specific Amazon product.  I modeled my code after [R Shiny: Handle Action Buttons in Data Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45739303/r-shiny-handle-action-buttons-in-data-table).  When the button is clicked, I need the user to navigate to a specific Amazon product page based on the ASIN in the data.table row.

```
  filteredData <- data.frame(
    Name = c('Dilbert', 'Alice', 'Wally', 'Ashok', 'Dogbert'),
    ASIN = c("B06Y4VRZTB",
             "B06Y4WGPBB",
             "B06Y4J9Z9V",
             "B06Y4V169H",
             "B06Y4TF1D1"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    row.names = 1:5)

  shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
    inputs <- character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
    }
    print(inputs)
    inputs
  }

  df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(
      filteredData %>% mutate(Amazon.Button = shinyInput(actionButton,
                                               nrow(filteredData),
                                               'button_',
                                               label = "Amazon",
                                               onclick = paste0("window.open('https://",
                                                                AmazonSiteLink,
                                                                "/gp/product/",
                                                                ASIN,
                                                                "/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=",
                                                                AssociateTag, "')")))
  ), escape=FALSE)
```

The issue is that every button ends up with the same URL picking up only the first ASIN value.  I want the ASIN value to be what is in the ASIN value for the row.

```
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06Y4VRZTB/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&amp;tag=my0000-00&#39;
```

I tried to create the button with every row, but get other errors such at, "Warning: Error in mutate_impl: Column `Amazon.Button` must be length 5 (the number of rows) or one, not 3"

```
  df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(
      filteredData %>% mutate(Amazon.Button = actionButton(inputId = paste0('button'),
                                               label = "Amazon",
                                               onclick = paste0("window.open('https://",
                                                                AmazonSiteLink,
                                                                "/gp/product/",
                                                                ASIN,
                                                                "/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=",
                                                                AssociateTag, "')")))
  ), escape=FALSE)
```

[image: Table with Name and ASIN for link]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that you try to pass an `R` object (list) (`actionButton`) to `mutate`. The list happens to has length `3` but `mutate` expects the same length as the dataframe. What you want is to take this object and convert it to the corresponding string. As you are anyways not using `Shiny's` reactivity on these buttons, I would recommend to construct the `HTML` yourself instead of using `actionButton` (untested, as you did not provide a  [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ):

```
library(tidyverse)
filteredData %>% 
   mutate(Amazon.button = map_chr(ASIN,
      ~ tags$button(class = "btn btn-default",
                    type  = "button",
                    icon("amazon"),
                    "Amazon",
                    onclick = paste0("window.open('https://",
                                     AmazonSiteLink,
                                     "/gp/product/",
                                     .x,
                                     "/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=",
                                     AssociateTag, 
                                     "')")
                    ) %>%
         as.character()
      )
   )
```

Comment: Hi @thothal, I used your solution to add button, but the icon did not show. I would like to show button with icon and without label. I have no idea to handle this issue. Any help will be appreciated.