# Using icons for shiny renderDataTable extension buttons

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using renderDataTable in my shiny app to create a datatable. I further use the "option" on the server side to add extension buttons such as copy, save, PDF, and CSV. Instead of buttons, I would like to show icons on the screen

Here is the code I have on the server side:

```
    output$table.summary<-renderDataTable({
      # some data to create a datatable ...  
      ,
      server = FALSE,
      extensions = c("Buttons"), 
      options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                 buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
                 scrollX = TRUE)
      )
```

The above code shows buttons on the screen for each of the actions listed under options (e.g., copy, csv, etc.); however, instead of buttons, I would like to use icons.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841346/adding-an-image-to-shiny-action-button ?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not going to work. The solution in that post is for when you create an action button and then try to use an icon for it.Here, the buttons are automatically created as a part of renderDataTable function on the server side of your app.

Answer (score 4):

You can add icons to buttons like this:

```
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("DataTable"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars}, 
    extensions = c("Buttons"),
    options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                   buttons = list(list(extend = "excel", text = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>'), 
                                  list(extend = "csv", text = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>')),
                   scrollX = TRUE)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Which results in: 
[image: Buttons icons]

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please point me to some sort of documentation regarding what you suggested here? I want to better understand the text class. For example, how should I code for a pdf button or an alternative Excel icon shape. Thank you!