# Can we introduce image already in memory to shiny button?

Tags: r, shiny

according to answer from @JorisMeys to [adding-an-image-to-shiny-action-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841346/adding-an-image-to-shiny-action-button).
We can introduced web image to button. but can we directly use image already in the environment (or memory)?

quote from @JorisMeys
Thanks to Joris.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        actionButton("goButton", "", icon = icon("play-circle")),
        tags$button(
          id = "reset_button",
          class="btn action-button",
          icon("close")

        ),
        tags$button(
          id = "web_button",
          class = "btn action-button",
          tags$img(src = "http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/button_play_89677.jpg",
                   height = "50px")
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        textOutput("text")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    out <- reactiveVal("Nothing")
    observeEvent(input$goButton,{
      out("Go Pushed")
    })
    observeEvent(input$reset_button,{
      out("Resetted")
    })
    observeEvent(input$web_button,{
      out("From the web")
    })
    output$text <- renderText({out()})
  }
)
```

Comment: So you can put your image into `www` folder where `ui.R` and `server.R` are. If the folder isn't there create one. Put all your images there and then you can read it in as `tags$img(src = "name of your image")`

Comment: Thanks, @PorkChop I was trying to avoid the time consumed. But after second thought, the time could be ignored.